Cross-covariance propagation
Suppose we have $\mathbf{y}=f(\mathbf{x})$ being known $\Sigma_{xx}$. Then, according to the propagation law of covariances,
$\Sigma_{yy}=\mathbf{J}\Sigma_{xx}\mathbf{J}^T$,
with $\mathbf{J}$ the Jacobian of $f(\mathbf{x})$. The question is, how the cross-covariance matrices $\Sigma_{xy}$ and $\Sigma_{yx}$ can be computed?
I have an old lecture notes where for the function $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{N}^{-1}\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{P}\ell$, where $\mathbf{N}$ and $\mathbf{P}$ are symmetric matrices, the result
$\Sigma_{\ell x}=\Sigma_{\ell\ell}(\mathbf{N}^{-1}\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{P})^T$
is stated, but I don't know how the hell it is deduced. The text says only that "applying the covariance propagation law..."
